# Autocomplete Not Firing on Child Element of div with display:none Attribute after showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete, asp.net-ajax

I have a div element that has its display attribute set to none in CSS.  I'd like to have a child element of this hidden div to use jQuery UI's autocomplete.  When I turn the 'display:none' off, it works fine.  When I show the div with the .show() method, the autocomplete does not work. Here is the div:

```
<div class="FloatingDiv" id="SNOMEDValueSelector" title="Select SNOMED Concepts" style="width:550px;">
    <div style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;">
        <div class="container" style="height:50px">
            <div id="ConceptTypeDiv" class="left-column">
                <label for="ConceptType" style="width:100%;">Concept Type:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("ConceptType", null, new { @class = "select", style = "width:95%;" })
            </div>
            <div id="DiagnosisStatusDiv" class="right-column-two-thirds" style="display:none;">
                <label for="DiagnosisStatus" style="width:100%;">Diagnosis Status:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("DiagnosisStatus", null, new { @class = "select", style = "width:95%;" })
            </div>
            <div id="OrderTestCheckBox" class="right-column-two-thirds" style="display:none;">
                <div style="float:left;width:10%">&nbsp;</div>
                <div style="float:left;width:25%">
                    <label for="chkOrder" style="font-size:.9em;">Order Test:</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chkOrder" value="Order Test" id="chkOrder"/>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:63%">
                    <label for="TestResults" style="width: 90%; font-size: .9em">Test Results:</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("TestResults", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:90%;" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 40px">
            <div class="left-column" style="width: 41%">
                <label for="SearchTerm" style="width: 90%; font-size: .9em">Search Term:</label>
                @Html.TextBox("SearchTerm", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:90%;" })
            </div>
            <div class="center-column" style="width: 15%">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="button" value="Populate" class="button-small" id="Populate" onclick="SearchDiscreteValues();" />
            </div>
            <div id="ValueTextBox" class="right-column" style="width: 42%;height:40px">
                <div style="container">
                    <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="button" value="Clear" class="button-small" id="Clear" onclick="ClearContents();" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 63%;">
                        <label for="Value" style="width: 95%;">Modifier Value:</label>
                        @Html.DropDownList("Value", null, new { @class = "input-box", style = "width:90%;", multiple = "multiple"})
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 6%;">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <a id="ValueLink" href="javascript:displayValueWindow();" style="width: 100%">...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the autocomplete code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SearchTerm").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetConceptsAutocomplete","ClinicalData")',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    SearchString: $('#SearchTerm').val(),
                    ConceptType: $('#ConceptType').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { 
                            label: item.Description, 
                            value: item.Description, 
                            id: item.ID 
                        };
                    }));
                },

            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {

            $("#SearchTerm").val(ui.item.label);

        }
    });
});
```

I looked at the Source for the page in the browser, and the element is rendering.

What am I missing?  Can this not be done, or do I have to bind the autocomplete to the element after it is shown?  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, jQuery loses some kind of binding when you show and hide a div.  The solution was to add a class to the element you wish to use autocomplete with then bind the autocomplete to the document.keyup.autocomplete event.

Here is the razor syntax that produces the textbox with the new class:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchTerm", null, new { @class = "input-box AutoComplete", style = "width:90%;" })
```

and here is the  binding for the keyup.autocomplete:

```
 $(document).on("keyup.autocomplete", '.AutoComplete', function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetConceptsAutocomplete","ClinicalData")',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    SearchString: SearchTerm,
                    ConceptType: ConceptID
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { 
                            label: item.Description, 
                            value: item.Description, 
                            id: item.ID 
                        };
                    }));
                },

            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $target.val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
});
```